# 2 diff. blob format

Tags: vb.net, format, blob

Kindly find bellow code that read a column with 2 diff blob format.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If (OleDbConnection1.State And ConnectionState.Open) <> 0 Then
        OleDbConnection1.Close()
    End If

    OleDbConnection1.ConnectionString = "Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Data Source=PORTLOB;Persist Security Info=True;Password=123456;User ID=Administrator;oledbreportislongforlongtypes=1;lobmaxcolumnsize=20480;longdatacompat=1;allowgetdatalobreaccess=1;"
    'MaximumInlineLobSize=32; HexParserOption=Binary;
    OleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand = OleDbSelectCommand1
    OleDbSelectCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT P_IMAGE FROM PORTLOB WHERE ID=(" & Text1.Text & ") "
    OleDbSelectCommand1.Connection = OleDbConnection1

    DataSet11.PORT_IMAGE.Clear()

    OleDbConnection1.Open()

    Try
        OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet11, "PORT_IMAGE")
        Dim c As Integer = DataSet11.Tables("PORT_IMAGE").Rows.Count
        If c > 0 Then
            Dim bytBLOBImage() As Byte = DataSet11.Tables("PORT_IMAGE").Rows(c - 1)("P_IMAGE")
            Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(bytBLOBImage)
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("NO PHOTOS")
        End If
    Catch Ex As OleDb.OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message)
    End Try

    OleDbConnection1.Close()

End Sub
```

I have 2  blob format  in the same column as the following:
1-  Colour picture start with 0000  WIDTH=480        HEIGHT=640
2-  B&W (Black and white) picture start with FF  B&W  WIDTH=153        HEIGHT=208

I am using DB2 VER10.5 AND VS 2010, I get the below error when I try to read them

System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
So, How can I solve the parameter error to be able to read both format?

Thanks for your co-operations.

Comment: Why do you appear to have a typed `DataSet` but then you're using a data adapter instead of a table adapter and then treat the `DataSet` as untyped? You should make up your mind and use one or the other.

Comment: As for the question, how was the data stored in the database generated in the first place?

Comment: Side note: `Option Strict On`. [Read More](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement)